# Having both username and email but using email to authenticate users in django-rest-auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

With most tutorials, I see people use either email or username. I want to have both fields but using only the email to authenticate users with Django-rest-auth, as the email will be verified and is very important. but the username also has its importance in my app.

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def _create_user(self, email, fullname, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
    now = timezone.now()
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    fullname = fullname
    user = self.model(
        email=email,
        fullname=fullname,
        is_staff=is_staff, 
        is_active=True,
        is_superuser=is_superuser, 
        last_login=now,
        date_joined=now, 
        **extra_fields
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

  def create_user(self, email, fullname, password, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(email, fullname, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

  def create_superuser(self, email, fullname, password, **extra_fields):
    user=self._create_user(email, fullname, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fullname']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

serializers.py

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    '''
    a custom serializer that overides the default rest-auth, and for
    the user to register himself
    '''
    username = None
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    fullname = serializers.CharField(required=True)


    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()

        return {
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'fullname': self.validated_data.get('fullname', ''),
        }
```

Note: I am using Django rest auth to authenticate users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own Authentication backend class from `ModelBackend` and override `authenticate` function.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class EmailAndUsernameBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()

        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(email=username) | Q(username=username))
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

And you should add (or replace with django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend) to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in `settings.py`

For example:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    ...
    'users.backends.EmailBackend',
]
```

Note: If you have another authentication backends, like OAuth or Social login, you should add your backend to end of list.

Comment: So if I am getting what you are saying, I need to take at least 2 steps

Comment: First this is what my AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS is like


```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

Comment: 1) You say I should add a EmailAndUsernameBackend(ModelBackend) that you specified,        
2) I should replace the ‘django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', I am guessing is to the custom one that was specified,          
3) Do I have to do anything to my models.py also?

Comment: 1) Correct.
2) Yes replace it with that, but add ` 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend'` first
3) No, as far as i see.

Comment: lastly the "EmailAndUsernameBackend(ModelBackend)", do I just create a file in the root directory?

Comment: Wherever you want. For example if you have app named `foo`, create file named `backends.py` and write those line under that file. Then add `foo.backends.EmailAndUsernameBackend` to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`